# PySNMP Agent timeout when execute GETNEXT from remote host

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I am starting with PySNMP, the provided example, woroks very good:

http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#implementing-scalar-mib-objects

The example says that it works with command: "snmpwalk -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6" and it is right, it works (only in localhost)

The problem if that I execute the code from another machine (in the same LAN) it timeouts.

I already checked firewal, antivirus, etc and it looks like that SNMP request is arriving OK, but when pysnmp detects that it comes from another hist is generates bad data that are interpreted like ICMP.

Can someone helps me to make the example work from another machine diferent to localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Agent is listening on the IP address you query or 0.0.0.0 and no firewall in the path which can block 161/UDP packets either way.

PySNMP does not produce ICMP messages, that can only be done by OS network stack or firewall.

To see what is happening inside pysnmp you could enable its [debugging](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/contents.html#using-these-examples).